# Need REST api for "Add to Wishlist" in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, wishlist, android

I want REST api for "Add to Wishlist" in Magento 2, and also need to know in which folder to place and the endpoint

Comment: Refer following for creating Whilist API. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229452/magento-2-wish-list-of-customer-using-api

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Create a module Test_Mobileshop

Please follow the below steps with the file paths

> 2.app/code/Test/Mobileshop/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/wishlist/items" method="GET">
        <service class="Test\Mobileshop\Api\WishlistManagementInterface" method="getWishlistForCustomer"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/wishlist/add/:productId" method="POST">
        <service class="Test\Mobileshop\Api\WishlistManagementInterface" method="addWishlistForCustomer"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>    
</routes>
```

> 3. app/code/Test/Mobileshop/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Test\Mobileshop\Api\WishlistManagementInterface" type="Test\Mobileshop\Model\WishlistManagement" />
</config>
```

> 4. app/code/Test/Mobileshop/Api/WishlistManagementInterface.php

```
<?php
/**
 * A Magento 2 module named Test/Mobileshop
 *  
 */
namespace Test\Mobileshop\Api;

/**
 * Interface WishlistManagementInterface
 * @api
 */
interface WishlistManagementInterface
{

    /**
     * Return Wishlist items.
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return array
     */
    public function getWishlistForCustomer($customerId);

    /**
     * Return Added wishlist item.
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     * @param int $productId
     * @return array
     *
     */
    public function addWishlistForCustomer($customerId,$productId);

}
```

> 5. app/code/Test/Mobileshop/Model/WishlistManagement.php

```
<?php
/**
 * A Magento 2 module named Test/Mobileshop
 *  
 */
namespace Test\Mobileshop\Model;

use Test\Mobileshop\Api\WishlistManagementInterface;
use Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProvider;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory as ProductImageHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation as AppEmulation;
/**
 * Defines the implementaiton class of the WishlistManagementInterface
 */
class WishlistManagement implements WishlistManagementInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_wishlistCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Wishlist item collection
     *
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection
     */
    protected $_itemCollection;

    /**
     * @var WishlistRepository
     */
    protected $_wishlistRepository;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepository
     */
    protected $_productRepository;

    /**
     * @var WishlistFactory
     */
    protected $_wishlistFactory;

    /**
     * @var Item
     */
    protected $_itemFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer
     */
    protected $_customer;

    /**
     *@var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
     */
    protected $productImageHelper;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storemanagerinterface;

    /**
     *@var \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
     */
    protected $appEmulation;

    /**
     *@var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $_productload;

    /**
     *@var \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory
     */
    protected $countryfactory;

    /**
     * @param CollectionFactory $wishlistCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $wishlistCollectionFactory,
        WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
        AppEmulation $appEmulation,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryfactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storemanagerinterface,
        ProductImageHelper $productImageHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productload,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ItemFactory $itemFactory
    ) {
        $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory = $wishlistCollectionFactory;
        $this->_wishlistRepository = $wishlistRepository;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_wishlistFactory = $wishlistFactory;
        $this->countryfactory = $countryfactory;
        $this->storemanagerinterface = $storemanagerinterface;
        $this->_itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->_productload = $productload;
        $this->appEmulation = $appEmulation;
        $this->productImageHelper = $productImageHelper;
        $this->_customer = $customer;
    }

    /**
     * Get wishlist collection
     * @deprecated
     * @param $customerId
     * @return WishlistData
     */
    public function getWishlistForCustomer($customerId)
    {

        if (empty($customerId) || !isset($customerId) || $customerId == "") {
            throw new InputException(__('Id required'));
        } else {
            $collection =
                $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory->create()
                    ->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId);
            $baseurl = $this->storemanagerinterface->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product';
            $wishlistData = [];
            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                $productInfo = $item->getProduct()->toArray();
                if ($productInfo['small_image'] == 'no_selection') {
                  $currentproduct = $this->_productload->load($productInfo['entity_id']);
                  $imageURL = $this->getImageUrl($currentproduct, 'product_base_image');
                  $productInfo['small_image'] = $imageURL;
                  $productInfo['thumbnail'] = $imageURL;
                }else{
                  $imageURL = $baseurl.$productInfo['small_image'];
                  $productInfo['small_image'] = $imageURL;
                  $productInfo['thumbnail'] = $imageURL;
                }
                $data = [
                    "wishlist_item_id" => $item->getWishlistItemId(),
                    "wishlist_id"      => $item->getWishlistId(),
                    "product_id"       => $item->getProductId(),
                    "store_id"         => $item->getStoreId(),
                    "added_at"         => $item->getAddedAt(),
                    "description"      => $item->getDescription(),
                    "qty"              => round($item->getQty()),
                    "product"          => $productInfo
                ];
                $wishlistData[] = $data;
            }
            return $wishlistData;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add wishlist item for the customer
     * @param int $customerId
     * @param int $productIdId
     * @return array|bool
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function addWishlistForCustomer($customerId, $productId)
    {
        if ($productId == null) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__
            ('Invalid product, Please select a valid product'));
        }
        try {
            $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $product = null;
        }
        try {
            $wishlist = $this->_wishlistRepository->create()->loadByCustomerId
            ($customerId, true);
            $wishlist->addNewItem($product);
            $returnData = $wishlist->save();
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {

        }
        return true;
    }    

    /**
     * Helper function that provides full cache image url
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageUrl($product, string $imageType = ''){
        $storeId = $this->storemanagerinterface->getStore()->getId();
        $this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
        $imageUrl = $this->productImageHelper->create()->init($product, $imageType)->getUrl();
        $this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();

        return $imageUrl;
    }
}
```

> 6. Please execute deploy commands upgade and compile etc..
> 7. Open postman app and test the same.
>      [image]

Please let me know whether you have any questions?

Comment: how to pass dynamic customer id ?customer_id=416 can i pass any variable instead  416

Comment: Is it work with post request?

Comment: [2020-06-20 05:32:24] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5eed9f686690b; Message: The "array" class doesn't exist and the namespace must be specified. Verify and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5eed9f686690b; Message: The \"array\" class doesn't exist and the namespace must be specified. Verify and try again. at /opt/lampp/htdocs/m233/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, LogicException(code: 0): The \"array\" class doesn't exist and the namespace must be specified.

Comment: @devmage r u got solution

Answer (score 0):

You can read guide about REST API.
http://alankent.me/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/

I read & practice and now I can do anything about REST API.

Comment: Isn't there any api for wishlist directly?

Comment: hum, you read to reference, it's helpful for you.

Comment: anyways thnx a lot

Comment: MagentoOdoo.com i tried that but ended up with : 
{
  "message": "Request does not match any route.",
  "trace": null
}
i tried the 1st example from : http://alankent.me/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/

Comment: [2020-06-20 05:32:24] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5eed9f686690b; Message: The "array" class doesn't exist and the namespace must be specified. Verify and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5eed9f686690b; Message: The \"array\" class doesn't exist and the namespace must be specified. Verify and try again. at /opt/lampp/htdocs/m233/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, LogicException(code: 0): The \"array\" class doesn't exist and the namespace must be specified.

Answer (score 0):

Wishlist is integral part for any eCommerce platform and We wish Magento guys would have included them in the core features. So we have taken the initiative and added these features by taking out the fork from the github. We are waiting for Magento guys to Merge our pull request. In the meanwhile you can take use the following forks for your online store:

WishList: https://github.com/manish-ip/magento2

Or you can download our free plugin from the following link :

WishList API Plugin: http://www.ipragmatech.com/products/wishlist-rest-api-magento/

Comment: I started to process your Pull Request  https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/5233 and made a Code Review of your proposed changes for Wishlist API. Here you can read main considerations you should apply to make us merge current PR - https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/5233#pullrequestreview-23452027

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help to you.

```
/**
* Add wishlist item for the customer
* @param int $customerId
* @param int $productIdId
* @return array|bool
* @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
*/
public function addWishlistForCustomer($customerId, $productId)
{
    if ($productId == null) {
        throw new LocalizedException(__
        ('Invalid product, Please select a valid product'));
    }
    try {
        $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        $product = null;
    }
    try {
        $wishlist = $this->_wishlistRepository->create()->loadByCustomerId
        ($customerId, true);
        $wishlist->addNewItem($product);
        $returnData = $wishlist->save();
    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {

    }
    return true;
}
```