# Magento 2 : Wish list of customer Using API

Tags: magento2, api

Get **wishlist** of customer using **Magento 2** API.

I refereed [Magento Dev](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html) but, I'm not able to find wishlist for customer.

Comment: Wishlist module doesn't have REST API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please find the Below Answer For Your Question for customer Wishlist.

To create webapi in Magento 2, we need to create a file in

> app/code/ExtensionName/ModuleName/etc/webapi.xml

in **Webapi.xml** Place below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/wishlist/product/:customerid" method="GET">
        <service class="ExtensionName\ModuleName\Api\HelloInterface" method="displayWishlist"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

> app/code/ExtensionName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

Then in **di.xml** Place below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="ExtensionName/ModuleName\Api\HelloInterface"
                type="ExtensionName/ModuleName\Model\Hello" />
</config>
```

As Per the above di.xml file Create HelloInterface adn Hello

> app/code/ExtensionName/ModuleName/Api/HelloInterface.php

Replace the code in **HelloInterface.php**

```
<?php
namespace ExtensionName\ModuleName\Api;

interface HelloInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param int customer id
     * @return mixed 
     */
    public function displayWishlist($customer_id);
}
```

Next Create **Hello.php** in below Path

> app/code/ExtensionName/ModuleName/Model/Hello.php

Place below code in Hello.php

```
<?php
namespace ExtensionName\ModuleName\Model;
use ExtensionName\ModuleName\Api\HelloInterface;

class Hello implements HelloInterface
{
            private $customer_id;
            private $wishlist;
            public function __construct(
            \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist
            ) {
                $this->wishlist = $wishlist;
            }

            public function displayWishlist($customer_id) {
            $customer_id = 1;
            $wishlist_collection = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customer_id, true)->getItemCollection();

            $wishlist_item = array();
            $i=1;
            foreach ($wishlist_collection as $item) {
            $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
            $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
            $WishlistItemId = $item->getWishlistItemId();
            $wishlist_item[$i]['productName'] = $productName;
            $wishlist_item[$i]['productId'] = $productId;
            $wishlist_item[$i]['WishlistItemId'] = $WishlistItemId;
            $i++; 
        }
            return $wishlist_item;  
        }
}
```

For More reference please find the below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: hello i am getting fallowing error. 
<message>%fieldName is a required field.</message>

Comment: You have to mention resource reference as "anonymous"  like <resource ref="anonymous"/> @SarveshTiwari

Comment: is itwork for post req ?

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to answer provided by learning_coder:
Replace code in Webapi.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/wishlist/product/:customer_id" method="GET">
        <service class="District\Customapi\Api\WishlistInterface" method="displayWishlist"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

It was an issue with parameter customer_id. Updating it would fix the issue.