# Add to wishlist for api in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I have created an api for wishlist.

If I add the **same product with option** to **wishlist** for **second time**,

then I got the new product with same option for every **addtowishlist**.

I already refer below link...
[Magento 2 : Wish list of customer Using API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229452/magento-2-wish-list-of-customer-using-api)  . But it does not help me.
Because it get only wishlist items for customer.But i need to add the **same product with option** to **wishlist** for **second time** condition

```
try {
            $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
            $product->setStoreId(1)->save();
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityExceptionNoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $product = null;
        }
        if (!$product || !$product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
            $message = __('We can\'t specify a product');
        }
        try {
            $requestParams = [
                'product_id' => $productId,
                'super_attribute' => [$sizeAttributeId => $sizeoptionId],
                'store_id' => 1
            ];

            $wishlist = $this->_wishlistRepository->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true);
            $buyRequest = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($requestParams);
            $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);

            if (is_string($result)) {
                $message = $result;
            }
            $wishlist->save();
            $message = __('Added to your Wishlist.');
            $status = true;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $message = __('We can\'t add the item to Wish List right now: %1.', $e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $message = __('We can\'t add the item to Wish List right now: ');
        }
```

Comment: This will help you `https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229452/magento-2-wish-list-of-customer-using-api`

Comment: .Magento 2 : Wish list of customer Using API . This link for get wishlist items ..Does not meet my requirement.I need add same for second time scenario.