# Get wishlistitems using customer id

Tags: magento2, wishlist

How to get wishlist items collection using customer id ?

Thanks

```
 public function removeWishlistForCustomer($customerId, $productId)
    {
        $wish = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId);
        $items = $wish->getItemCollection();
        foreach ($items as $item) 
        {
            if ($item->getProductId() == $productId) 
            {
                $item->delete();
                $wish->save();  
                return "You have successfully remove item from wishlist"; 
            }
        }
        
    }
```

I am getting no data in  `$items = $wish->getItemCollection();`

Comment: use the WishlistManagement.php model file logic in your custom file https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109651/need-rest-api-for-add-to-wishlist-in-magento-2/252735#252735

Comment: Please take a look at the updated question